# Javascript Email Validation, I want without case sensitive for .com in email id

Tags: javascript

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re =/^[a-z_A-Z\-0-9\.\*\#\$\!\~\%\^\&\-\+\?\|]+@+[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+(.com)$/;  
return re.test(email); 
}
```

Javascript Email Validation. Function working but .com is case sensitive (only lower case is accepting in these function). I want without case sensitive in .com.

Answer (score 2):

Add "i" after var re:

```
var re =/^[a-z_A-Z\-0-9\.\*\#\$\!\~\%\^\&\-\+\?\|]+@+[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+(.com)$/i;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

In this case: double checking of a-z AND A-Z is redundant. Use:

```
var re =/^[a-z_\-0-9\.\*\#\$\!\~\%\^\&\-\+\?\|]+@+[a-z\-0-9]+(.com)$/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

**recommended solution:**

1) Use the ignore case flag `i` like following: `/your regex/i`. You then also can omit the uppercase letters in your character classes.

other possibilities (not recommended though):

2) convert your string to lower case `email.toLowerCase()`. You can drop the uppercase letters in your character classes with this one.

3) include the following pattern `(\.[Cc][Oo][Mm])` instead of `(.com)` - Too verbose for what it does.

Sidenote:

You need to escape the dot before com: `(\.com)` or else it will match an arbitrary character

Comment: Variant 1 is waste (He is using a regex allready).

Variant 2 does not work. Should be `\.[cC][oO][mM]`.

Variant 3 is the best. It does not make the pattern longer/complexer.

Comment: @jgb they are not recommended, but possible, I explicitely state the 3rd one as recommended solution, so what's your problem?

Comment: Everything is fine. I would simply note that variants 1-2 are bad. I would recommend to set the recommended variant to the begin.

Comment: @jgb edited the post to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the characters in the email address to lowercase before doing the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as email id is case insensitive

```
    return re.test(email.toLowerCase());
```